# Repository Pattern Class Generator

Tags: design-patterns

I have some Entity classes and now need to create Repositories for these classes. Which tools can help me to create Repository classes for my entity classes?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any tools that will create the repository classes for you. If you're keen to avoid the proliferation of repositories, as you have many entities that will need one, you can use a generic repository with a type parameter (`Repository<TEntity>`). This way you can minimise the effort and duplication.